# Update iOS database via file or via json?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm currently updating an app which I developed quite a long time ago. I'm wondering what's the best way to update the sqlite database via REST api.

I'm thinking about the following process:

- When the user is opening the app the device will send the current database version (locally stored in a `.plist`) to a REST webservice.
- The webservice compares the client version to the web version - if there is a new one available I would like to send the entire database to the client (no delta updates).

Now I'm thinking what's the better way to "send" the data to the client. Download a sqlite? Or create a JSON at the webservice (what means somehow overhead). The sqlite is currently about 100 kb.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: If the DB were quite large you'd want the scheme that minimizes the amount of data sent and the duration of the operation.  But 100kb is chicken feed, so whichever way fits your overall design best should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

- there is no user data to preserve and there won't be any in the future, e.g. if your database is completely static
- it is safe to assume its size is not going to increase significantly
- your database model hasn't changed and is highly unlikely to change in the future
- you're 86% sure that you'll never again be requiring a proper api to a similar online database, featuring delta updates and a generic format like json

go ahead and transmit that replacement sqlite. Otherwise, do it properly!

Comment: So you would prefer something generic like JSON and see over the overhead to provide a clear solution in case of any changes in the app code?